# Creating a Matrix class in ruby. The [] method

Tags: ruby, class, methods, matrix, arguments

I've been assigned to create a new matrix class. I cannot use the require 'Matrix'.

I have this to access the element of the matrix, where @matrix is an array of arrays.

```
def [] (i, j)
  @matrix[i][j]
end
```

if i try to access it like this:

```
@a[0][0]
```

it wont work. (wrong number of arguments)

but if i do it like this:

```
@a.[](0,0)
```

or

```
@a[0,0]
```

it works just fine. 
Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Just a question, does this also work as you expect it to do? `def [] (*cords); cords.inject(@matrix){|m, c| m[c]} end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a method that either calls it self recursively or checks how many arguments that are passed to the function. It is hard to say if this works as I do not have you entire class, but something like this might work:

```
def [] (*cords)
  return @matrix[*cords] if cords.size == 1
  @matrix[cords.first][cords.last]
end
```

Or a recursive version that works for any number dimensions:

```
def [] (*cords)
   cords.inject(@matrix){|m, c| m[c]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def [] (i, j)
  @matrix[i][j]
end
```

According to the method `[]` it needs 2 arguments. But `@a[0][0]` doesn't do that,as here you are passing the method `[]` only 1 argument,ie.e `0`. only. So you got the error. But `@a.[](0,0)` or `@a[0,0]` are perfect,as you are sending 2 arguments to the method `[]`. When you write `@a[0,0]`,then Ruby internally does the method call as `@a.[](0,0)`.

> how would you modify the code so @a[0][0] works?

Here is a code example:

```
class Matrix
    def initialize(a)
        @matrix=a
    end
    def [](*a)
         a.size == 1 ? @matrix[*a] : @matrix[a.first][a.last]
    end
end
a = [[1,2,3],[4,7,5],[11,21,33]]
m = Matrix.new(a)
p m[2,2] # => 33
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand what you are saying, but how would you do that then? i mean, how whould you modify the code so @a[0][0] works?

Comment: Your code does not work for single index calls. You need to change `@matrix[a]` to `@matrix[*a]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def [](i)
  @matrix[i]
end
```

would do it, I guess. FWIW, Ruby's Matrix has [] implemented same as you: [[](i,j)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-5B-5D)